# Issue with adobe air and backbone url attribute

Tags: javascript, file, air, adobe, backbone.js

I'm having some issues using adobe air in conjunction with backbone. The problem is that in the beginning of my program, I specify a url for my Backbone.Controller which uses that to set the url attribute of my Collection. And when the program starts, Backbone uses that url, to get a response and calls the parse function in my collection, where I use that response and construct appropriate model from. The problem is that at the beginning, if I specify a relative path to the .xml file, it works, but if I specify a full path, it doesn't work, meaning that the response argument in the parse function for the collection is null. Here is some code:

```
//works
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.myApp = MyApp({ url : "/data/file.xml" } )
})
///..
var MyApp = Backbone.Controller.extends({
 /* setup routes */
 initialize: function(opt){
   this.tree = new MyTree();
   this.tree.url = opt.url;
 }
})
//...
var MyTree = Backbone.Collection.extends({
 model: myTreeModel,
 parse: function(response){ /* do stuff with response */ }
});
```

The above works if I use relative path, but If I use full path like this

```
window.myApp = MyApp({ url : "file:///C:/Users/userName/MyProject/data/file.xml" } )
```

the response sent to parse is undefined. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: You can't access local files from a web page. Imagine the security hole!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use their application scheme, so prepending app: worked.

Comment: probably he means that instead of :

    `{ url : "/data/file.xml" }`

he changed it to :

    `{ url : "app/data/file.xml" }`

Comment: It's been a while but I believe so. @Chev